# How do I Validate If input type text isn't empty - PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, if-statement, contact-form

I am trying to make a contact form, and need to make a validation for input type=text, however, it seems to have some mistakes, which I cannot find. Can you help me? Here is the code:

```
    <td>
Name*:<input type="text" name="name" id='name2' class="name1" />
</td>
<td>
Email*:<input type='text' name="email" class="email1" id='email2'/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
Message*: <br />

<textarea name='msg' style="float:right;" class="msg1" id='msg2'>
</textarea>
</td>
```

and here:

```
<?PHP
$nml = strlen($_POST['name']);
$eml = strlen($_POST['email']);
$msgl = strlen($_POST['msg']);

if(isset($_GET['sent'])) {
    if($nml<1) { 
    if($eml<1) {
    if($msgl<1) {   
        exit("<script>document.getElementById('name2').style.borderColor='red'; document.getElementById('email2').style.borderColor='red'; document.getElementById('msg2').style.borderColor='red';</script><center><font color='red'>Name*, Email* and Message* fields are required</font></center>");
    }
    exit("<script>document.getElementById('name2').style.borderColor='red'; document.getElementById('email2').style.borderColor='red';</script><center><font color='red'>Name* and Email* fields are required</font></center>");
    }
    exit("<script>document.getElementById('name2').style.borderColor='red'; <center><font color='red'>Name* field is required</font></center>");
    }
    if($eml<1) {
        if($msgl<1) {
            if($nml<1) {
        exit("<script>document.getElementById('email2').style.borderColor='red'; document.getElementById('name2').style.borderColor='red'; document.getElementById('msg2').style.borderColor='red';</script><center><font color='red'>Email*, Name * and Message* fields are required</font></center>");
            }
            exit("<script>document.getElementById('email2').style.borderColor='red'; document.getElementById('msg2').style.borderColor='red';</script><center><font color='red'>Email* and Message* fields are required</font></center>");
    }
        exit("<script>document.getElementById('email2').style.borderColor='red';</script><center><font color='red'>Email* field is required</font></center>");
    }
    if($msgl<1) {
        if($nml<1) {
            if($eml<1) {
                exit("<script>document.getElementById('msg2').style.borderColor='red'; document.getElementById('name2').style.borderColor='red'; document.getElementById('email2').style.borderColor='red';</script><center><font color='FF0000'>Message*, Name* and Email* Fields are required</font></center>");
            }
            exit("<script>document.getElementById('msg2').style.borderColor='red'; document.getElementById('name2').style.borderColor='red';</script><center><font color='FF0000'>Message* and Name* Fields are required</font></center>");
        }
        exit("<script>document.getElementById('msg2').style.borderColor='red';</script><center><font color='FF0000'>Message* Field is required</font></center>");
    }

}
?>
```

please help me fix it, i tried so many times but i just cant get to fix it. its just way too hard for me

Comment: many errors - example: your forget to close tag `<script></script>` after `('email2').style.borderColor='red';` and `<center>` `<font>` are deprecated HTML tag

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is this section of logic:

```
if($nml<1) { 
    if($eml<1) {
        if($msgl<1) {   
            exit(/* simplified for clarity */);
        }
        exit(/* simplified for clarity */);
    }
    exit(/* simplified for clarity */);
}
```

You have nested the if statements, so the ONLY time any of them will trigger is if `$nml < 1`

To properly do this, I would suggest using the `OR` operator - `||`, or else putting each if separately.

OR method:

```
if($nml<1 || $eml<1 || $msgl<1) {   
    exit(/* simplified for clarity */);
 }
```

If each message needs to be different, then separate if statements, like so:

```
if($nml<1) { 
    exit(/* simplified for clarity */);
}

if($eml<1) {
    exit(/* simplified for clarity */);
}

if($msgl<1) {   
    exit(/* simplified for clarity */);
}
```

Finally, the method you are using has several extra, non-necessary pieces to it.  A cleaner method would be to remove your lines where you're getting the length of the inputs:

```
/* Remove */
$nml = strlen($_POST['name']);
```

And instead, use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) - which checks if the index is set, as well as if it's empty, which will prevent notices from being thrown.

```
if(empty($_POST['name']) { 
    exit(/* simplified for clarity */);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use trim function with your post variables, ex. $nml = strlen(trim($_POST['name']));

Answer (score 0):

Use it:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['sent'])) {

    $nml = strlen($_POST['name']);
    $eml = strlen($_POST['email']);
    $msgl = strlen($_POST['msg']);

    if(empty($nml)) { 
        echo "<script>document.getElementById('name2').style.borderColor='red'; </script><center><font color='red'>Name* fields is required</font></center><br>";
    }
    if(empty($eml)) {
        echo "<script>document.getElementById('email2').style.borderColor='red';</script><center><font color='red'>Email* fields is required</font></center><br>";
    }
    if(empty($msgl)) {   
        echo "<script>document.getElementById('msg2').style.borderColor='red'; <center><font color='red'>Message* field is required</font></center><br>";    
    }

    if(empty($nml) || empty($eml) || empty($msgl)) {
         exit;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: This `if(isset($_GET['sent'])) {` doesn't match with `POST` values.